# How to determine the Server Name after installing SSMS v18?

Tags: sql-server, sql

I have just installed Sql Server Management Studio v18. In launching for the first time, the Server Type "Database Engine" appears automatically (which is fine).

However, I do not know the Server Name.

Checks made online show that it can be found in the Configuration Manager. However, it was removed in this release of SSMS. Can someone help me find the Server Name?

Answer (score 1):

> In launching for the first time... I do not know the Server Name.

I was in the same position you were: I had downloaded Sql Server Management Studio (SSMS), and had tried to launch it for the first time. I had a Server type: Database Engine, but no Server name.

[image: Server type: Database Engine, Server name: blank]

I had tried default server names (instance names) like `MSSQLSERVER`, `localhost`, and `.` to no avail. [Tips and tricks using SSMS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/tutorials/ssms-tricks?view=sql-server-ver15#find-the-error-log-location-if-you-cant-connect-to-sql-server) mentioned an `ERRORLOG.log` file I didn't have. [How to find server name of SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio) mentioned using the Sql Server Configuration Manager, which I also didn't have.

At this point, I realized something was wrong with my configuration. It turns out that before I installed SSMS, I should have [installed Sql Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads)!

I installed SQL Server 2019 Developer, and it gave me the instance name that verified I had an installation:

[image: Instance name MSSQLSERVER]

Then I could enter default server names such as `.` and `localhost` to connect!

Answer (score 0):

Try . as server name. This will connect to the server if it runs locally, or you can try MSSQLSERVER.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by **Server Name** you mean **Instance Name**, you could either:

- run `services.msc` and find the services named Sql Server. The
  instance name will be between brackets like this: 
  [Windows services - SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0GMN.png) (in my case there are two instances);
- or you could open Configuration Manager like this:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9844771/sql-server-configuration-manager-not-found/21759718#21759718.